# How do I exit a nested while loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, exit

EDIT: Since my program still doesn't work, I posted the entire method just in case there is another problem.

I want to exit this program if the user inputs 'n' when prompted:

```
 char again = 'y';
        while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
        { 
        String ans = IBIO.inputString ("Unscramble: OBORSLW (Hint: Shellder latches onto its tail.) ");
        int tries = 0;

        while (!ans.toLowerCase ().equals ("slowbro"))
        {
            System.out.println ("Incorrect. Wrong answer. Try again.");
            tries++;
            ans = IBIO.inputString ("\nUnscramble: OBORSLW (Hint: Shellder latches onto its tail.) ");

            if (tries > 3)
            {
                System.out.println ("The correct answer was SLOWBRO.");
                again = IBIO.inputChar ("Play again? (y/n) ");
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println ("Correct.");

        System.out.println ("\nQuestion #2 - ");
        String ans2 = IBIO.inputString ("\nUnscramble: RVLEGERA (Hint: It rolls down slopes without slowing down.) ");
        int tries2 = 0;
        while (!ans2.toLowerCase ().equals ("graveler"))
        {
            System.out.println ("Incorrect. Wrong answer. Try again.");
            tries2++;
            ans2 = IBIO.inputString ("\nUnscramble: RVLEGERA (Hint: It rolls down slopes without slowing down.) ");

            if (tries2 > 3)
            {
                System.out.println ("The correct answer was GRAVELER.");
                again = IBIO.inputChar ("Play again? (y/n) ");

                if (again != 'y' || again != 'Y')
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println ("Correct.");

        System.out.println ("\nQuestion #3 -");
        String ans3 = IBIO.inputString ("\nUnscramble: TYSGLA (Hint: It's almost invisible and is gaseous.) ");
        int tries3 = 0;
        while (!ans3.toLowerCase ().equals ("gastly"))
        {
            System.out.println ("Incorrect. Wrong answer. Try again.");
            tries3++;
            ans3 = IBIO.inputString ("\nUnscramble: TYSGLA (Hint: It's almost invisible and is gaseous.) ");

            if (tries3 > 3)
            {
                System.out.println ("The correct answer was GASTLY.");
                again = IBIO.inputChar ("Play again? (y/n) ");

                if (again != 'y' || again != 'Y')
                    break;
            }
        }
        printSlow ("Correct.");
        printSlow ("\nWell Done, " +name+ "! You have passed the test! I'm so happy for you!!");
        break;
    }
    }
```

Whenever I purposely input a false value multiple times, I get told the right answer, and can try again if I want to. This part works. However, if I don't want to continue, the program just continues by itself and proceeds to the next question. How can I stop the entire program?

Comment: `System.exit(0);` exits the program.

Comment: wait but i still want the player to continue playing if they press 'y'

Comment: `if (again != 'y') System.exit(0);`

Comment: wait but sometimes even when i press y it doesn't loop @Gendarme

Comment: Well, I guess it has to do with `IBIO.inputChar ("Play again? (y/n) ");` I do not know that method so I don't know what happens inside that.

Comment: @Gendarme I edited my post, and posted my entire method. Maybe you could help find the problem now.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I edited my post, and posted my entire method. Maybe you could help find the problem now

Answer (score 0):

```
 char again = 'y';
    while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
    {
        String ans = IBIO.inputString ("Unscramble: OBORSLW (Hint: Shelder latches onto its tail.) ");
        int tries = 0;
        boolean flag= false;
        while (!ans.toLowerCase ().equals ("slowbro"))
        {
            System.out.println ("Incorrect. Wrong answer. Try again.");
            tries++;
            ans = IBIO.inputString ("\nUnscramble: OBORSLW (Hint: Shelder latches onto its tail.) ");

            if (tries > 3)
            {
                System.out.println ("The correct answer was SLOWBRO.");
                again = IBIO.inputChar ("Play again? (y/n) ");
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==true){
        break;       
}
```

your mean this ?

Comment: umm when i do this, i can't repeat the loop and when i press n , my program goes to the next method. so no, i don't mean this.

Comment: I edited my post, and posted my entire method. Maybe you could help find the problem now

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have modify codes to suit your requirements. Please check it out.

Original: I think first of all you have to write out what is your `IBIO` class here so that people are able to help you debug.

I have found out `IBIO` class online and tested your program, but it has performed correctly.

Below is my code.

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    private static boolean verifyAnswer(String candidate, String answer) {
        if (candidate.toLowerCase().equals(answer))
            return true;
        else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect. Wrong answer. Try again.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static boolean playGame(int questionNumber, String answer, String question) {
        String candidate;
        System.out.println("Question #" + questionNumber + " - ");
        int tries = 0;
        do {
            tries++;
            if (tries > 3) {
                System.out.println("The correct answer was " + answer + ".");
                char again = IBIO.inputChar("Play again? (y/n) ");
                if (again != 'y' && again != 'Y')
                    System.exit(0);
                else
                    return false;
            }
            candidate = IBIO.inputString(question);
        } while (!verifyAnswer(candidate, answer));
        System.out.println("Correct.");
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (!playGame(1, "slowbro", "Unscramble: OBORSLW (Hint: Shellder latches onto its tail.) ")) ;
        while (!playGame(2, "graveler", "Unscramble: RVLEGERA (Hint: It rolls down slopes without slowing down.) ")) ;
        while (!playGame(3, "gastly", "Unscramble: TYSGLA (Hint: It's almost invisible and is gaseous.) ")) ;
    }
}
```

IBIO.java:

```
//---- IBIO - Below are simplified input and output methods ----
//===========================================================
// IBIO Standard Input and Output
//  These methods must be copied into your program(s).
//===========================================================
public class IBIO {
    static void output(String info) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }

    static void output(char info) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }

    static void output(byte info) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }

    static void output(int info) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }

    static void output(long info) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }

    static void output(double info) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }

    static void output(boolean info) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }

    static String input(String prompt) {
        String inputLine = "";
        System.out.print(prompt);
        try {
            inputLine = (new java.io.BufferedReader(
                    new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String err = e.toString();
            System.out.println(err);
            inputLine = "";
        }
        return inputLine;
    }

    static String inputString(String prompt) {
        return input(prompt);
    }

    static String input() {
        return input("");
    }

    static int inputInt() {
        return inputInt("");
    }

    static double inputDouble() {
        return inputDouble("");
    }

    static char inputChar(String prompt) {
        char result = (char) 0;
        try {
            result = input(prompt).charAt(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = (char) 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static byte inputByte(String prompt) {
        byte result = 0;
        try {
            result = Byte.valueOf(input(prompt).trim()).byteValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static int inputInt(String prompt) {
        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = Integer.valueOf(
                    input(prompt).trim()).intValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static long inputLong(String prompt) {
        long result = 0;
        try {
            result = Long.valueOf(input(prompt).trim()).longValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static double inputDouble(String prompt) {
        double result = 0;
        try {
            result = Double.valueOf(
                    input(prompt).trim()).doubleValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static boolean inputBoolean(String prompt) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            result = Boolean.valueOf(
                    input(prompt).trim()).booleanValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
//=========== end IBIO ===========================================//

}
```

My environment: Intellij Community 2016.1.1 + jdk 8 + Windows 7 x64

Comment: I edited my post, and posted my entire method. Maybe you could help find the problem now @juniver

Comment: @lkjhgfdsa4321 I think your issue comes from `if (again != 'y' || again != 'Y')`. It should be `if (again != 'y' && again != 'Y')`. Anyway, I have posted a more modular code base on your full codes to suit your requirements. Please check it out.